# How do you keep track of data for simple C++ programs?

Tags: c++

Say I want to build a simple program on my computer that is kind of like a journal for me. 
I want to say run a command goodDay() every time I finish all my homework and that will up my count every time. And I can run howMany() to retrieve how many good days I've had but obviously I would have to keep my current count somewhere on my computer, where would that be?

Do I just make a text file and keep adding one to the number on it each time? How do actual developers do it?

Comment: Obviously, you need to save your data somewhere, and then re-load it later.  How you actually do that is a bit too broad to answer, as there are many options available (file vs database vs Registry), many formats available (text vs binary vs XML vs JSON), etc.  You need to narrow the focus of your questioning.

Comment: I guess I'm just learning how to read and write from files and I just thought of this as one way to store data like, even when your program isn't running for when I want to start a personal project, but I couldn't think of any other ways so I was just asking if there were better ways. My question re-worded I guess would be, would this way work and is it commonly used/are there way better obvious ways?

Comment: "*would this way work*" - of course. "*is it commonly used*" - yes, though HOW it is used varies. "*are there way better obvious ways?*" - that is a matter of opinion. There are *different* ways, whether they are *better* is subjective.

Comment: I had a similar situation to deal with. If the data is really simple, like the one you described, just numbers, then you may try storing them as text. The way is to use `std::fstream` in the standard library to write them into a file. If however the data becomes complex, for example `vector<int>`, or `vector<vector<int>>`, you may want to store them as binary. The related topic is serialization. Related libraries are boost.serialization and cereal for example. If you just started with C++, that might be a distraction, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can write info to a file or set up a local database. Location should not matter.
If all you need to do, is to look at count of gooddays, write a number. 
For more analysis, you can create a file / table with columns (date, description, rank) in it. 
Rank can be used as rating. aka 10 means you finished it.

With info above instead of just a counter, you can analyze your progress better and make changes.

Answer (score 0):

"I would have to keep my current count somewhere on my computer, where would that be?"

You really have a broad question, but that's not unusual for a beginner. The *where* part of the question has an answer that differs from OS to OS. On Windows, you would probably store this under a per-user `appdata` directory, on Linux and Apple you'd store this in the $HOME directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you can store this information in file or a database.
Here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-handling-c-classes/ you have some tutorial on file management.